# Trouble using posix_kill in php

Tags: php, linux, yii

I'm using `php 5.5.11` and when I try to call `posix_kill` I get the following error:
    `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function posix_kill() in /var/www/.../someScript.php on line 861`

I'm not sure what more information is relevant, feel free to ask.

Comment: what os are you running?

Comment: please take a look at the output of `php -m` in your console.. if posix isn't listed there you have to install it via your package manager

Answer (score 5):

You need to install PHP's `posix` extension which implements that function. Without that extension the function simply is not defined, which leads to the error.

How to install such an extension package depends on your operating system. Easiest is in Linux where you can search, identify, download and install packages with a single click inside the software management system.